# How to manage internal Node.JS modules

Tags: node.js, github, dependencies, npm

What would be the preferred way to handle internal modules within a node.js application?

I mean, currently we have a fairly big application and there are several dependencies, installed via npm. We have `node_modules` in `.gitignore`. Therefore it's not in the repository. We use `npm shrinkwrap` to freeze the modules versions, so, upon deployment, an `npm install` puts together eveything we need into `node_modules`.

The problem is, since out app is getting bigger, we want to split it to smaller modules. Now, if I create a `foo` module and put it in `node_modues`, I need to allow it in the repo, which does not seem so neat to have both ignored and checked out modules in `node_modules`.

We can not publish these on npm registry because they are not really "public".

Is there any obvious solution that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I just stick my private libraries/modules into a `/lib` directory under the project instead of in `npm_modules`. This way they can also be included in Git.

Comment: Yeah it's very common to have a lib folder and require('./lib/myThing')

Comment: With lib folder, I need to name the modules explicitly each time I need them. I need them a lot :) From all sorts of places. I don't really like `require("../../../../../lib/foo")`. Having them in node modules makes access much more easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with your aesthetic of not mixing 3rd-party non-repo stuff with your in-house revision-controlled contents.

The NODE_PATH search path variable can help you here, you can use a different directory with contents under revision control.

http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Depending on your appetite for flexibility vs complexity, you can consider a build step that actually copies your various node modules from wherever you keep them, into an output directory (probably "named node_modules" but not necessarily).

Comment: NODE_PATH seems to be the most elegant approach here. I just can keep stuff in lib/ and reference them by name in require. Since the environment variable is properly documented, I don't think it can be considered as a hack or something :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

A common solution is to store the modules in a private Git repository somewhere, and then use a `git://` URL as a dependency; npm knows how to clone repositories as dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I evaluated this but then, I need to somehow authorize our servers to access the private git repos. Either via the servers public key or ip range. That'd work though.